# grub2 create menu entry to skip the current disk os while booting

Tags: debian, grub2, usb-drive

I created 2 partitions on my pendrive. The first partition is big one and I use it for general purpose file storage. The second partition is small one and I made debian-jessie install in this one. I use this for recovery purposes on different systems.

Whenever I connect the pendrive and power on any system, when it boots from usb, it shows debian entry on usb and other entries that are irrevelant since they change from system to system. To boot into the hard disk I need to unplug the pendrive and reboot. Or I had to boot into pendrive debian and `#update-grub`.

That makes rebooting twice. I wish I could just have a defaulted menu entry on pendrive grub that just skips booting any os on pendrive and go to 2nd disk's mbr and boot from that disk. Is that possible?

Comment: Are you saying that the computer directly boots to USB?

Comment: It boots from usb if the bios has boot priority set to usb over hard disk. I just want to be able to skip this using a menu entry. Changing bios setting boot priority is not a good idea, when the system is not your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and add an entry like:

```
menuentry "Load OS in /dev/sda1" {
    set root=(hd0,1)
    chainloader +1
}
```

Remember to run `sudo update-grub` after this.

This will chainload the OS on MBR of `/dev/sda1`